# Hack language: generics for collection types

Tags: generics, hhvm, hacklang

Why is this code working?

```
<?hh // strict
function test(Vector<int> $v):void {
    print_r($v);
}

test(Vector {1, array("I'm an array"), 3});
```

Shouldn't it throw an error? What is the `<int>` supposed to be for?

Answer (score 7):

This won't throw an error in HHVM, but will in the Hack tools. This is due to HHVM currently ignoring generics, so it is just checking if `$v` is a `Vector`.

Running the Hack tools (`hh_client`) will first complain about the top level statements and, if you correct that by wrapping the call to `test` inside a function, will correctly complain about trying to pass a `Vector<mixed>` as a `Vector<int>`.

Comment: Relevant documentation on how to get `hh_client` set up is here: http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/install.hack.bootstrapping.php

As additional color, note that type erasure semantics for generics aren't the way things will necessarily work forever; this is something we may allow the runtime to have knowledge of sometime in the future.